# Change the position of compass in mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

I need to change the position of compass from left to right in app.It always shows in left.Is it possible to change position??

```
  // change compass position
    try {
        assert mapFragment.getView() != null;
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton").getParent();
        parent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0, n = parent.getChildCount(); i < n; i++) {
                        View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        // position on right bottom
                        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
                        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
                        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                        rlp.rightMargin = rlp.leftMargin;
                        rlp.topMargin = 25;
                        view.requestLayout();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the needed solution to align the Compass button on Top Right corner:

```
View compassButton = mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapCompass");//to access the compass button
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) compassButton.getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START,0);
rlp.topMargin = 50;
```

This will change it's `RelativeLayout` params to align to the Top Right corner.
**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Does your code work when we want to align it to top-right? I think that is the question

Comment: It would be great if you can put compass button on top-right as I have also tried but unable to align the compass button to top-right, yes I have been able to align it bottom-left.

Comment: Really appreciate this Dude, Thanks

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan  Check the update.

Comment: Its working, +1 for you

Comment: The compass already has some rules that you might have to remove. If you want it bottom, remove the align_top etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  GoogleMap.setPadding() method: for your compass position

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding